# Search live Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

It is necessary to reach the search entries instantly, but why can I cause such an error?

This error : POST https://localhost/theme/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Following my code:
`HTML`

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>
 <div id="datafetch">Search results will appear here</div>
```

`functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fetch(){

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <?php  }

add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'operator' => 'NOT'
    );
    $query = new WC_Product_Query(
        array(
            'tax_query' => $tax_query,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
            'post_type' => 'post'
        )
    );
    $products = $query->get_products();
    if($products) {
        foreach( $products as $product) {
            echo '
      <a href=" '. get_permalink($product->id) .' "> '. $product >get_name() .' </a>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}
```

`debug.log`

```
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(303): data_fetch('')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php(187): do_action('wp_ajax_data_fe...')
#4 {main}
```

i am getting an error like this

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn’t make much sense. Can you rephrase? You mention an error, are you getting one? What is the error?

Comment: sorry i updated it now

Comment: Actually, what I'm looking for is to see the data instantly while searching when I come to the search entry.

Comment: Well you have one parse error and one notice. `$product >get_name()` is missing `-` so it should be `$product->get_name()`. `$product->id`, if I remember correctly is protected, it should be accessed by the method `$product->get_id()`. Also i'm not sure why `'post_type' => 'post'`, `WC_Product_Query` queries products

Comment: I didn't apply what you said but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: *I didn't apply what you said*, did you mean that you applied what I said but it still doesn't work? Could you update your code with the current updates?

Comment: You should check your error log for the actual errors.

Comment: detail I missed $product ->get_name()
I wrote exactly this $product >get_name() . Solution found. thanks